# Can you use a function's returned value in a if statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, nodes

how to return a result of a function without having to declare the variable?
how to return the result of the function on a single line?
how to return the result of the function inside the if?

Can you use a function's returned value in a if statement?

```
if ( await winthorglobal.SqlVerificarSeOPedidoExiste(PedidoNumeros).rows === PedidoNumeros )
```

Result: `undefined`

Comment: Can you share more details and code? Like which line is throwing error etc

Comment: Probably just an ambiguity in precedence…? `(await win....(PedidoNumeros)).rows`…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result with a small change to the code, the key is placing brackets around

```
(await winthorglobal.SqlVerificarSeOPedidoExiste(PedidoNumeros))
```

We can then call .rows on the result, e.g.

```
(await winthorglobal.SqlVerificarSeOPedidoExiste(PedidoNumeros)).rows
```

This should behave the way you wish.

If you don't place the brackets around the await statement, you're effectively trying to get the .rows property on a Promise, which will obviously return `undefined`

```js
const winthorglobal = { 
   SqlVerificarSeOPedidoExiste(n) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve({ rows: n })), 100)
   } 
}

async function testIt() {
    const PedidoNumeros = 10;
    if ((await winthorglobal.SqlVerificarSeOPedidoExiste(PedidoNumeros)).rows === PedidoNumeros) {
       console.log("All good")
    }
}

testIt()
```